# PythonAnywhere requests session raising exception 'connection aborted'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pythonanywhere

I am trying to launch my script to PA and while it works locally it does not work on PA and I cannot figure out why.  I have the paid version of PA so I can access this site that is not whitelisted. Here is my script:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    # initates the login session
    if os.path.exists(document_report + '.pdf'):
        # initates the login session
        post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers = dict(referrer = 'https://www.example.com/loginpage'))

        #This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
        REQUEST_URL = f'https://www.example.com/{stuff}/{document}'
        #gets the request URL
        r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
        # saves to directory


        with open('./digests/1.pdf', 'wb') as j:
            j.write(r.content)
            j.close()



    else:
        post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers = dict(referrer = 'https://www.example.com/loginpage'))

        #This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
        REQUEST_URL = f'https://www.example.com/{stuff}/{document}'
        #gets the request URL
        r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
        # saves to directory


        with open(document_report + '.pdf', 'wb') as j:
            j.write(r.content)
            j.close()
```

When I run the code, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 275, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
        six.raise_from(e, None)
      File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
        httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 275, in _read_status
        raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/legalaide/emailProcessorV2.py", line 567, in <module>
        post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers = dict(referrer = 'https://www.example.com/loginpage'))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581, in post
        return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
        raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I tried it again locally, and it still works.  Any insight into a solution would be amazing!

Comment: You should not be calling `j.close()` manually when you are using the `with` keyword

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot that.  It doesn't solve my problem, but it does clean it up :)

Comment: Are you still getting the "Remote end closed connection without response" error?  If so, it might be that the site you're connecting to is blocking access from cloud systems like PythonAnywhere.

Comment: Yes, it turned out that you were right, the site blocked cloud systems.